# Plotting monthly weather data from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have extracted monthly weather data for a certain location from 1978 to 2018, and the data is stored in a dictionary.

```
{((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-01-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '32.5', 'tmon': '-9.2'},
 ((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-02-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '11.6', 'tmon': '-14.7'},
 ((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-03-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '38.0', 'tmon': '-4.1'}}
```

The dictionary is constructed like this, keys being tuples of location and date, and values monthly rainfall and average temperature. I have to plot the temperature for each month separately on one graph.

How can I plot for example the average temperatures for January? I do not know how to choose only the temperatures for one month in the dictionary, or do I even have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grouped bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = {((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-01-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '32.5', 'tmon': '-9.2'}, ((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-02-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '11.6', 'tmon': '-14.7'},((65.03371, 25.47957), '1978-03-01T00:00:00Z'): {'rrmon': '38.0', 'tmon': '-4.1'}}
l, d = zip(*[[a.split('T')[0], [float(b['rrmon']), float(b['tmon'])]] for (_, a), b in data.items()])
r, t = zip(*d)
x, width = np.arange(len(l)), 0.35
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, r, width, label='rrmon')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, t, width, label='tmon')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(l)
ax.legend()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think if I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to transform the data into a form where you break the data down into {month_indicator:{data...}}. Where month indicator gives you an explicit month. If that's true my strategy would be as follows:

For key, value pair in your original data:
Isolate your date / date-string by indexing the tuple. If it's a string, turn it into a datetime object. You can do this by using datetime.datetime.strptime() function, it has a few rules you can look up to get the data into the manner you need.

Once it's turning into a datetime objects, it have the attribute date.month which gives 1 for Janaury, 2 for Febuary, 3 for March, ... etc. That gives you a way of finding all Januaries or other months when you iterate through the data.

Then you can reassign the data into the format {1: [temp1, temp2, ..., temp n], 2: [temp1, temp2, ..., temp n], etc.]}

From there you have a hundred different ways of getting averages such as sum(dict['month_key']) / dict['month_key'], importing you favorite module with a mean function, etc.

Afterwards, you'd have a set of data with a month-to-(avg. temp) set that can be plotted easily in a matplotlib bar graph.

I hope this helped!